# How to find differences in nested JSON objects and highlight them

Tags: javascript, diff

I have a problem that I cannot resolve for a long time now. I have two nested JSON objects and I need to what are the additions in the second one and highlight them(add a CSS class).

For instance if I had:

```
let obj1 = {
    blocks: [
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: 'This is text for my project.',
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: 'This is in both and needs no change',
        },
      },
    ],
  }

  let obj2 = {
    blocks: [
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text:
            'This is text for my project. This is some text that will not be in the first object.',
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: 'Things are becoming complicated in programming',
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: 'This is in both and needs no change',
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

After they are compared I'd like for the second obj to be like:

```
let obj2 = {
    blocks: [
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text:
            'This is text for my project. <span class="new-text">This is some text that will not be in the first object.</span>',
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: '<span class="new-text">Things are becoming complicated in programming</span>',
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: 'This is in both and needs no change',
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

I tried looking into the diff library from google But can't find to change other things that pure strings or regular objects(not nested)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "I cannot resolve for a long time now".. show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: As I wrote in the last paragraph, I tried using google's Diff library to search for differences in my strings, but position also matters so it didn't work. Then I tried npm package diff which also had an option for searching differences in json objects, but not nested ones. I need something like in the example provided.

Comment: We understand, but we would like to see the code you have written so far so that we can help you improve that. We only (re)start ftom scratch if your code is worth nothing..

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this,
if I am wrong please correct me, I am a beginner.

```
   let obj1 = {
    blocks: [
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: 'This is text for my project.',
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: 'This is in both and needs no change',
        },
      },
    ],
  }

  let obj2 = {
    blocks: [
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text:
            'This is text for my project. This is some text that will not be in the first object.',
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: 'Things are becoming complicated in programming',
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'paragraph',
        data: {
          text: 'This is in both and needs no change',
        },
      },
    ],
  }
obj2["blocks"].map(item => {
      var str = item.data.text;
      obj1["blocks"].map(item2 => {
        var obj2Str = item2.data.text;
        if (str.indexOf(obj2Str) > -1) {
          var endStr = str.substr(obj2Str.length);
          item.data.text = endStr.length >0 ? obj2Str + '<span class="new-text">'+ endStr +'</span>' : obj2Str;
        }
      });
    });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, from what I see here, if I console log arr3 I get an empty array with 3 empty objects.

Comment: My bad kindly check obj2  as was modifying it.
sorry for the inconvenience.